# What is the probability that 3 flowers appear between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m?

Tags: probability, poisson-process

The flowers appear according to a Poisson process with rate 3 per hour.

Given that 8 flowers appeared between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., what is the probability that 3 of them appeared between 9 a.m. and 9:20 a.m.?

The answer given is $${8 \choose 3} \frac{1}{3}^3 \frac{2}{3}^5$$ I understand ${8 \choose 3}$ because we need to know the probability of 3 of the 8 flowers appearing. Also, we are looking a third of the hour. Hence, ${\frac{1}{3}^3}$.

But where does $\frac{2}{3}^5$ come into play? I assume it the probability that the other 5 flowers do not appear.

Lastly, is there a way to formulate a correct answer using a Poisson process?

Thanks!

Comment: Haha interesting username. Can you double check the source of your question, the setup doesn't really make sense to me. What is the meaning of "3 types of flowers A, B, C with respective probabilities 1/3,1/6,1/2" and, whatever these probabilities represent, why then would they have the same mean for their poisson distribution?

Comment: @PrinceM The flower types/probabilities are not relevant in this question and was used for another question. My bad, I shouldn't have included them. Hopefully this clears up any confusion.

Comment: If $N(t)$ is a Poisson process, then conditioned on $N(t) = n$, the joint distribution of the interarrival times $T_1,\ldots,T_n$ is the same as the order statistics $U_{(1)},\ldots,U_{(n)}$ where $U_i\sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,t)$. How to go from there to a binomial distribution, I am not sure.